# Cannot iterate through collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

OK... I've been beating my head against the wall on this one for hours. What seems like a simple thing to fix, I can't come up with a proper solution. This is an MVC 3 website.

I have a web service which successfully returns an Entity Framework Customer object in my Controller with one record. It can contain many Customer objects, but in this case, it just has one record.

```
YeagerTechWcfService.Customer custs = db.GetCustomers();
return View("Index", custs);
```

When trying to iterate through the Customer object, I'm getting the following error msg:

> Cannot cast
>   '((System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage)(this)).ViewData.Model'
>   (which has an actual type of
>   'YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer') to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

It obvioulsy can't cast my Customer object to an IEnumberable object and I don't know why.... Can't you cast the EF objects to an IEnumerable object when trying to go through each "Customer" record?

In my View, I have the following code. The ViewData.Model has the data of the Customer record in it. 
@model YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer

```
@if (ViewData.Model != null)
    {
        foreach (YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer item in (IEnumerable<YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>)ViewData.Model)
```

Can someone please let me know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Edited your post and you can see that your code is not complete. Can you update with full code?

Comment: and whats the return of `db.GetCustomers();`

Answer (score 2):

You have a mix-up of list (or enumerable) of customers and a single customer. It start with the following line:

```
YeagerTechWcfService.Customer custs = db.GetCustomers();
```

The declaration on the left side clearly says it's a single customer, yet the method name on the right side indicates that you're somehow expecting a list of customers.

In the view, you declare the model to be a single customer:

```
@model YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer
```

But then you don't use the strongly typed instance variable `Model` but instead use the untyped property `ViewData.Model` and cast it to something it isn't (thus getting the error).

As it stands now, `db.GetCustomers()` returns a single customer (not a list with a single customer). So remove the *foreach* loop from the view and just write:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    <p>@Model.FirstName @Model.LastName</p>
    ...
}
```

The other approach is to fix `db.GetCustomers()` so it indeed returns a list of customers. Then you have to change your controller to:

```
List<YeagerTechWcfService.Customer> customerList = db.GetCustomers();
return View("Index", customerList );
```

and your view:

```
@model List<YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>

@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer item in Model)
    {
        <p>@item.FirstName @item.LastName</p>
        ....
    }
}
```

There shouldn't be any need to use `ViewData.Model` or type cast. They just cover type mismatches.

Comment: Simply doing your answers don't quite help. I changed the method in my web service from public Customer GetCustomers() to public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers(). I am executing the following query inside this method as follows: IEnumerable<Customer> customer = null;

            var customerEntity = from c in DbContext.Customers

Comment: I am getting an error on the last statement as follows: Cannot cast 'customerEntity.ToList()' (which has an actual type of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType4<short,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,System.DateTime,System.DateTime?>>') to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>' It seems like the ToList method will not let me convert it to an Ienumerable object. This is the purpose of the ToList method; to be able to convert a list to an Ienumerable. How can I resolve this?

Comment: This is the statement I'm getting the error on: customer = (IEnumerable<Customer>)customerEntity.ToList();

Comment: One thing is that you should decide whether you use `IEnumerable` or `List`, either one or the other. But mixing them causes some of your problems. Then I need to see the declaration of `DbContext.Customers` to further help you on the error your getting.

Comment: I think this is the right approach. Your View's @model MUST have a List of Customers in order to iterate the Model object on a foreach loop. You say "It can contain many Customer objects, but in this case, it just has one record", so pass your view a IEnumerable or List of customers, not a Customer object. It seems that your service is returning a single object and not a list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with EF. You simply can't cast `Customer` object to `IEnumerable<Customer>`.

I'm not sure why you want to iterate in the view when you pass a `Customer` object from the controller as the Model.

If your `GetCustomers()` method's return type is `YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer` then you can create a list and pass it to view.

```
var customers = new List<YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>(db.GetCustomers());
return View("Index", customers);
```

I suggest you review your design.

Comment: Simply doing your answers don't quite help. I changed the method in my web service from public Customer GetCustomers() to public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers().

Comment: I am executing the following query inside this method as follows: IEnumerable<Customer> customer = null;

Comment: IEnumerable<Customer> customer = null;

            var customerEntity = from c in DbContext.Customers

Comment: I am getting an error on the last statement as follows: Cannot cast 'customerEntity.ToList()' (which has an actual type of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType4<short,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,System.DateTime,System.DateTime?>>') to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>' It seems like the ToList method will not let me convert it to an Ienumerable object. This is the purpose of the ToList method; to be able to convert a list to an Ienumerable. How can I resolve this?

Comment: This is the statement I'm getting the error on: customer = (IEnumerable<Customer>)customerEntity.ToList();

Comment: @sagesky36 your LINQ query returns anonymous type. Try something like `from c in DbContext.Customers select c` where c is of type `YeagerTechWcfService.Customer`

Answer (score 0):

i cnt say for sure since i cant see your code but i am assuming that your view is set as a strongly typed Customer view if you change it to IEmumurable it should fix the problem

edit: change @model line from `Customer` to `IEnumerable<Customer>` and this should fix your error judging from the error message you have it set as a strongly typed view of type Customer which is only going to allow you to use a singular customer to use an `IEnumerable`  the view model line need to be redefined to mtch this or you will recieve this error forever   if this does not fix your error please update your question with the full source of your view so we can see everything

Comment: Simply doing your answers don't quite help. I changed the method in my web service from public Customer GetCustomers() to public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers().

Comment: I am getting an error on the last statement as follows: Cannot cast 'customerEntity.ToList()' (which has an actual type of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType4<short,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,System.DateTime,System.DateTime?>>') to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>' It seems like the ToList method will not let me convert it to an Ienumerable object. This is the purpose of the ToList method; to be able to convert a list to an Ienumerable. How can I resolve this?

Comment: This is the statement I'm getting the error on: customer = (IEnumerable<Customer>)customerEntity.ToList();

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

YeagerTechWcfService.Customer custs = db.GetCustomers()**.ToList()**;

**Update**
Here is code I have in existing website that returns an enumerable list and I iterate over the list in my controller.

```
public List<Subscriber> GetSubscribers()
{
    using (var database = new Data.MyCoolDatabase())
     {
        return database.Subscribers.ToList();
     }
}
```

In your view make sure your model statement is an IEnumerable like so...

```
@model IEnumerable<Newsletter.Web.Models.Subscriber>
```

Comment: It won't compile unless `YeagerTechWcfService.Customer` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Your comment is incorrect...ToList turns the DbSet into an IEnumerable object.  I'll update my answer with more detail.

Comment: look carefully what is on the left side of `=` in `YeagerTechWcfService.Customer custs = db.GetCustomers().ToList();`. can you assign a list to a `Customer` object?

Comment: Hey you're right! I missed the fact that sagesky36 wants to put an enumerable list into a single object. sagesky36 is most likely frustrated since he/she has spent hours on this and is unable to get this working. Perhaps you could serve a better purpose by editing your answer with a solution that actually helps rather than questioning his/her motives, voting my answer down, and pointing out how my answer has flaws. I think sagesky36 just wants an answer to the problem.

Comment: Simply doing your answers don't quite help. I changed the method in my web service from public Customer GetCustomers() to public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers(). I am executing the following query inside this method as follows: IEnumerable<Customer> customer = null;

            var customerEntity = from c in DbContext.Customers

Comment: I am getting an error on the last statement as follows: Cannot cast 'customerEntity.ToList()' (which has an actual type of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType4<short,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,System.DateTime,System.DateTime?>>') to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<YeagerTechWcfService.Customer>' It seems like the ToList method will not let me convert it to an Ienumerable object. This is the purpose of the ToList method; to be able to convert a list to an Ienumerable. How can I resolve this?

Comment: This is the statement I'm getting the error on: customer = (IEnumerable<Customer>)customerEntity.ToList();